# I have a string consisting of 0's and 1's. How do i store those 0's and 1's in binary format in a file?

Tags: c++, string, file, bit

Consider the string "`010010101`". I would like to store the above string in binary format in a file. I want to do this because when I execute the following code:

```
    ofstream out("file.txt");
    out << string;
```

the file size is too large. I would like to reduce the file size by storing the 0s and 1s in binary format in file.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the goal here. You have a string `010010101` that you would like to save directly as bits, rather than as character bytes?

Comment: Does the size of the string is divisible by 8 ?

Comment: So if you want to convert "0" and "1" characters into bits in a `char` or such, do you have written any code yet that attempts to do that?

Comment: You can read the string into a bitset (if you know the size) std::bitset<16> b(std::string("0101111001")); and then convert that to numbers e.g. by calling b.to_ullong()

Comment: yes i would like to save it directly as bits because i want to reduce the file size.

Comment: But then, as @Jarod42 said,  you must be either sure that the number of chars in your string is divisible by 8 or your must pad it otherwise.

Comment: i actually have a very long string of 0's and 1's .

Comment: How long approx.? (Why do you have a string in this format in the first place?)

Comment: Maybe you should use RLE encoding for your data. It is simple and could reduce the size of your file considerably if 0's and 1's show up consecutively for long sequences.

Answer (score 3):

You can write bytes to a file

e.g.

```
#include <fstream>
...
char buffer[100];
ofstream myFile ("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
myFile.write (buffer, 100);
```

Now we now how to write bytes all we need to know is how to convert our string to the byte values to be written.

Assuming your string is not encoded in unicode we can simply use the ascii table to find out that '1' represents numeric value 49 and '0' represent numeric value 48.

With this knowledge you can iterate trough each 8 characters of your string, substract 48 from each '1' or '0' will give you the numeric value. Than you shift the 8 numbers together until you have your byte. If you have less then 8 character you need to put leading zeros.

I was to lazy to write out the code, but I guess that with this knowledge you  should be able to write a nice working algorithm.

Comment: i am a beginner in c++. if anyone could write the code as @Giovanni told i would be grateful .

Comment: @user3266972 No-one on stack overflow is going to write your code for you - that's not what the site is for. We're here to help you learn to do it yourself, not to do it for you.

Comment: @user3266972: Just scroll down (or up) a little bit. I'm having lunch, so I have a bit of extra time.

Comment: @benubird thankyou for ur advice. here on i shall learn and not ask for code

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function to turn a string of `'0'` and `'1'` characters to a packed binary string:

```
string pack_bin (string const & s)
{
    string ret;
    ret.reserve ((s.size() + 7) / 8);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.size(); )
    {
        char c = 0;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 8; ++j, ++i)
            c = (c << 1) | ((s[i] != '0') ? 1 : 0);
        ret += c;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

and the reverse:

```
string unpack_bin (string const & s)
{
    string ret;
    ret.reserve (s.size() * 8);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; --j)
            ret += ((s[i] & (1 << j)) ? '1' : '0');

    return ret;
}
```

Note the following:

- If the length of the string is not a multiple of 8, you must store the length with the resulting string in order to be able to recover the exact string you had. Otherwise, the unpacked string will have extra zeros at the end.
- It's better to write the resulting string to a binary file, i.e. `ofstream out("file.txt", ios:binary);`

You can use the above routines like this:

```
// To write:
ofstream out ("file.txt", ios::binary);
out << pack_bin(str);

// To read back:
ifstream in ("file.txt", ios::binary);
string s;
in >> s;
s = unpack_bin (s);
```